# What causes an array error in JMF

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, mp3, jmf

In this code bellow I want to play an mp3 music file using JMF library. I have downloaded mp3.plugIn and added it to my project.

```
package mediaaa;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;
import javax.media.pim.PlugInManager;

       public class Mediaaa {

               public static void main(String[] args) {

       File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jovan\\Desktop\\music.mp3");

    try {

        Format inputMP3 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3);
        Format inputMPEG = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG);
        Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR);

        PlugInManager.addPlugIn("com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder", new Format[] { inputMP3, inputMPEG },
                new Format[] { output }, PlugInManager.CODEC);

        Player player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(file.toURI().toURL());

        player.start(); // Without this code works but there is no sound

    } catch (NoPlayerException | IOException | CannotRealizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

I get this error when I run my code:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2
at codecLib.mp3.i.a(Unknown Source)
at codecLib.mp3.i.char(Unknown Source)
at codecLib.mp3.Decoder.decode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder.process        (JavaDecoder.java:323)
at com.sun.media.BasicFilterModule.process(BasicFilterModule.java:322)
at com.sun.media.BasicModule.connectorPushed(BasicModule.java:69)
at com.sun.media.BasicOutputConnector.writeReport  (BasicOutputConnector.java:120)
at com.sun.media.SourceThread.process(BasicSourceModule.java:729)
at com.sun.media.util.LoopThread.run(LoopThread.java:135)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: so far I havent seen anyone saying "hooray I run JMF and mp3" - but I'm waiting for the encouraging note

Comment: it's evident why JMF goes down the drain - PlugInManager.addPlugIn("com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder", new Format[] { inputMP3, inputMPEG }, new Format[] { output }, PlugInManager.CODEC); - who needs this junk

Comment: But without it I got this error:  Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 32000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@707f7052
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@707f7052

Comment: First you need to add mp3 format, than you can play it. But still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm willing to try it and see if I get the same error-  can you give me where you put the mp3plugin and where do you have the jmf.jar? and wher did you get the mp3plugin from??

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view this is source from where you can download mp3.plugIn, after that you just add it as external jar.file to your project, you also need JMF library which can be downloaded from oracle site and it also needs to be included in your project, after that you can try to run my code above.

Comment: I absolutely can run the program - it plays the mp3 -maybe your IDE is corrupted your jmf.jar is corrupted or other things - try to run it from the command line

Comment: Now I have to find another way of playing an mp3 file...

Comment: This error is actually coming from mp3.plugIn library( there must be some bug ), it means that entire plugin won't work. Thank you anyway.